# Show existing content of file when editing it PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I open a `.ini`, then write some add some values to its parameters and then i saved it back.

My writing the content works perfectly fine, but when i open the file the previous content of that file is cleared.[**Maybe due to my write mode**].

What change should i do in my code to let user see what the previous content was when he edits a file.

```
file_get_contents($path.$filename); 

    /*Get All The datas from that file*/

    $this->data['params'] = $this->parameter_m->get();

    /*Getting the parameters to display on view*/

    $this->data['parameters']  = parse_ini_file($path.$filename,true);

    while (current($this->data['parameters']) ) 
    {
        $param_set = current($this->data['parameters']);
        $param_type = key($this->data['parameters']);

            foreach ($param_set as $key =>$value) 
            {

                $this->data['parameters'][$param_type][$key] = $this->input->post($key);

            } 

        next($this->data['parameters']);
    }

    $this->load->helper('file');

    $this->load->library('ini');

    $file = $path.$filename;

    $ini = new INI($file);

    $ini->read($file);



    $ini->write($file, $this->data['parameters']);
```

**My Write Function**

```
function write($file = NULL, $data_file = array(), $sections = TRUE) {
    $this->data_file = (!empty($data_file)) ? $data_file : $this->data_file;
    $this->file = ($file) ? $file : $this->file;
    $this->sections = $sections;
    $content = NULL;

    if ($this->sections) {
        foreach ($this->data_file as $section => $data_file) {
            $content .= '[' . $section . ']' . PHP_EOL;
            foreach ($data_file as $key => $val) {
                if (is_array($val)) {
                    foreach ($val as $v) {
                        $content .= $key . '[] = ' . (is_numeric($v) ? $v : $v ) . PHP_EOL;
                    }
                } elseif (empty($val)) {
                    $content .= $key . ' = ' . PHP_EOL;
                } else {
                    $content .= $key . ' = ' . (is_numeric($val) ? $val : $val ) . PHP_EOL;
                }
            }
            $content .= PHP_EOL;
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($this->data_file as $key => $val) {
            if (is_array($val)) {
                foreach ($val as $v) {
                    $content .= $key . '[] = ' . (is_numeric($v) ? $v : '"' . $v . '"') . PHP_EOL;
                }
            } elseif (empty($val)) {
                $content .= $key . ' = ' . PHP_EOL;
            } else {
                $content .= $key . ' = ' . (is_numeric($val) ? $val : '"' . $val . '"') . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }

    return (($handle = fopen($this->file, 'w+')) && fwrite($handle, trim($content)) && fclose($handle)) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Just for confirmation is the file is opened in write or append mode? Because when the file is open in write mode then previous content will get lost and then new content will get written into it.

Comment: @AlankarMore i got that before the write function i get all my data the probelm is in my write function, so what can i do so that when used open/edit files he can see the previous value, like we do for database records.

Comment: in which file you are about to make changes exactly?

Comment: In the file that I open just like database record

Comment: have you restarted your xampp after updating .ini file to apply latest changes in action?!

Comment: @Kunal  i am talking about the PHP in file, this is just another file like test.ini also its  values are different  not related to php

Comment: May this Pear extension will help you if you want to use. https://github.com/pear/Config_Lite

Comment: @AlankarMore thanks but i can't use it that will make me change my whole code

Comment: Okay, your code is correct but need some more time to answer it .but can you check the variable name at statement `foreach ($this->data_file as $section => $data_file) {` here for value you have used the `$data_file` and you have this variable name used for the function parameter so may be script get conflicts here, can you try with the different variable name. - just a suggestion.

Comment: @AlankarMore i was thinking the same, wait let me try if that's the issue

Comment: is your problem solved ?

Comment: @alankar I tried it but it didn't work